# Eigen Matrix[value], what does it mean?

Tags: c++, eigen3

In C++ using Eigen library writing the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Core>

using namespace Eigen;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Matrix3f mat;
    Matrix3f m[11];

    cout << mat << endl;
    cout << "\n" << m[11] << endl;
}
```

The first `cout` outputs:

```
-37392.8        4.57244e-41    -37378.8
4.57244e-41    -37206.4         4.57244e-41
-37223.2        4.57244e-41     8.40779e-45
```

The second one outputs:

```
           0 -2.51418e-31            0
 2.96401e+17 -1.10025e+33   2.9625e+17
 3.06324e-41            0  3.06324e-41
```

What does `[ ]` operator do?
How `mat[value]` is different from `mat`?
Another question :p why Eigen generates extremely large or small numbers, are they random?

P.S: on the second output, the zeros are always zeroes but the other numbers are changing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not `operator[]`. This is a C-style array.

```
int a[42];
```

defines an array of 42 `int`s named `a`.

In the same line, for a type `T` and positive integer `N`, this:

```
T bla[N];
```

defines an array of `N` objects of type `T`.

So your code

```
Matrix3f m[11];
```

defines an array of 11 `Matrix3f` objects.

The array indexing starts from 0, so the last valid index is 10, not 11 as in your code.
Due to Eigen not zero-initializing its objects, you would get random numbers when printing the values of the 0-10th elements.

Answer (score 3):

The declaration

```
Matrix3f m[11];
```

doesn't have much to do with `Eigen`. It's a plain raw array on the stack with 11 instances of `Eigen::Matrix3f`. And when you

```
cout << "\n" << m[11] << endl;
```

this is undefined behavior because you have an out of bounds index. `m` has 11 elements in total, and as indices start at 0 in C++, the last valid object in `m` is `m[10]`. Undefined behavior means your program could do anything - you should hence not try to interpret these results.

That being said, the first `cout` part is likely to be unaffected by the following UB. It shows the uninitialized values of the `Eigen` matrix.